# Работа с transform: rotate(45deg) для верстки ромба

Tags: css, html5

Как правильно указать свойство transform: rotate(45deg) при :hover, чтобы блок крутился, а иконка внутри нет? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше всего подойдут псевдоэлементы `:before` или `:after`. Которые мы и будем крутить. Можно вообще не оборачивать в блок иконку. Принцип из примера будет понятен.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
min-height: 100vh;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
        justify-content: center;
-webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
        align-items: center;
}
div {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: pink;
  font-size: 2em;
}

div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 2px solid lightgrey;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(0.24, 1.8, 0.68, 0.98);
  -o-transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(0.24, 1.8, 0.68, 0.98);
  transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(0.24, 1.8, 0.68, 0.98);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
          transform: rotate(0deg);
}

div:hover:before {
  border: 2px solid pink;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
          transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
```

Comment: В смысле "можно"? Нужно, иначе она крутится всегда будет, так как это вложенный в блок элемент. Если, конечно, при ховере не указать этой иконке крутиться в другую сторону, но это уже костыли на пустяке.

Comment: @VostokSisters Для вывода самой иконки у тега `<i>` используется псевдоэлемент `:before`. Если сделать квадрат из псевдоэлемента `:after` (этого же тега), то крутить можно именно его, а не всю конструкцию.

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: transparent;
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px 0 0 30px;
}

#logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: url(http://icons.veryicon.com/png/Media/Free%20Flat%20Multimedia/Dslr%20Camera.png);
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
}

#block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid red;
    transition:all .3s;
}

#wrapper:hover #block {
  width: 100px;
  transition:all .3s;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  height: 100px;
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="logo"></div>
  <div id="block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: надо объяснять в чем суть или и так понятно?